# How to use copyTo() without showing "destination" tab/sheet, keeping the user where he is (using Google Apps Script)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

there!

The functions below basically copies rows into another sheet. This is a tweaked sample of the code.
The issue I'm finding is:
When this copies the row(s) into the new sheet, that sheet becomes active. I'll delete it later, but the user gets dragged into this temporary sheet and I'd lie to know if there'd be a way to do it using `copyTo()` but without shifting tabs in front of the user.

```
/*
*It moves the order row into Production Sheet in WIP, as the user sets status Confirmed;
*/
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const dstSpreadsheetId = "XXXXXxxxxxxxxXXXXXXXXXX" // Please set the destination Spreadsheet ID.
  const destSheetName = 'Página23'

  //Maps the values to serve as criteria to decide if this should continue running
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const orderSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Orders');
  const activeSheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  const thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  const thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  const cellValue = e.range.getValue();
  if (activeSheetName == orderSheet.getName() && thisRow > 5 && thisCol < 13 && cellValue == 'Confirmed') {
      moveOrder(ss, orderSheet, thisRow, dstSpreadsheetId, destSheetName)
      orderSheet.getRange(thisRow, thisCol).setValue('')
    }
  }
}

function moveOrder(ss, orderSheet, thisRow, dstSpreadsheetId, destSheetName) {
  const orderHeaders = orderSheet.getRange(5, 1, 1, 13);//Gets the table headers.    
  const rowValues = orderSheet.getRange(thisRow, 1, 1, 13);//Gets the changed row

  const newSheet = ss.insertSheet('MoveOrderToWIP');//Creates a temporary sheet
  orderHeaders.copyTo(newSheet.getRange(newSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1), { contentsOnly: true });//Moves the headers into the temporary sheet
  rowValues.copyTo(newSheet.getRange(newSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1), { contentsOnly: true });//Moves the row into the temporary sheet

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I cannot understand the relationship between the function `installedOnEdit` and the function `moveOrder`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike! Just added a line where the second ```moveOrdes()``` is called. The problem is because when copying the range into a newly added sheet, the new sheet is activated and I'd like to have the copying happening while the user remain where he/she is. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. When I saw your updated script, it seems that `dstSpreadsheetId` and `destSheetName` are not used in `moveOrder` function. In your goal, you want to use only one Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, although I could understand your actual goal, in order to keep the active range even when `insertSheet` is used, I proposed a modification point in an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your actual goal, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your updated script, it seems that `dstSpreadsheetId` and `destSheetName` are not used in `moveOrder` function. Although I cannot understand whether you wanted to use only one same Spreadsheet, for example, when you want to keep the edited range as the active range even when the new sheet is inserted by `insertSheet`, how about the following modification?

#### Issue and solution:

- In your script, `ss` is `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`. In this case, when `insertSheet` is used, the activated ranges are changed. In this case, even when `ss` is used as `e.source`, the same result occurs. It seems that this is the current specification.
- When you want to keep the active range even when `insertSheet` is used, please use `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` instead of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`. By this, the active range is not changed even when `insertSheet` is used.

When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows. In this modification, your showing script is modified. Please be careful about this.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
const newSheet = ss.insertSheet('MoveOrderToWIP');
```

##### To:

```
const newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss.getId()).insertSheet('MoveOrderToWIP');
```

- By calling the Spreadsheet from outside, even when `insertSheet` is used, the active range can be kept. In this case, even when Sheets API is used, the same result occurs.

#### Note:

- In your script, after "MoveOrderToWIP" sheet was inserted, the script is run again, an error occurs. Because the same sheet name is existing in the Spredsheet. So, please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)

Comment: You should get acknowledged by Google as an exceptional, if not yet! Thank you! This is exactly what I was after!

Comment: @santosOnit Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too. As an important point, when `openById` is used, the simple trigger of `onEdit(e)` cannot be used. In this case, it is required to use the installable OnEdit trigger. Please be careful about this.

Answer (score 1):

#### All you need is from range and to range there is no need to actually activate the either of the sheets

`fromRange.copyTo(toRange);`

Probably the insertSheet() is making it the active sheet.  So make some other the sheet the active sheet after doing the insert

Comment: Hi, Cooper! I don't think I'm explicitly activating it and I'd like to know how to avoid it at all. Thank you!